# Creating a QGIS plugin with executable code, from an existing script

Tags: qgis

I have a script generated in part by myself and in (most) part by ChatGPT. When running the script in the QGIS python window, the script opens a dialogue box in QGIS allowing a user to enter a private 9 digit SBI number, which calls from the UK Rural Payments Agency to import field parcels tied to that SBI number. I would like to create a simple QGIS tool for the processing toolbox which I can execute when needed.

I have tried following QGIS plugin and script tutorials to adapt my code to no avail; I am totally new to Python and can't figure it out at this point. Also, when I save the script to the QGIS script repository it executes the script upon opening QGIS (which I don't want it to do). Any guidance on this would be really useful.

Here is my script:

```
##Import Field Parcels from SBI##

import urllib
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

class InputDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        # create line edit for user input
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.setPlaceholderText("Enter 9-digit SBI number")
        
        # create button to confirm input
        self.button = QPushButton("OK")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        
        # create vertical layout for the dialog
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

# create instance of InputDialog
dialog = InputDialog()

# set the window title of the dialog
dialog.setWindowTitle("SBI Import")

# show the dialog and get user input
result = dialog.exec_()
if result == QDialog.Accepted:
    sbi = dialog.line_edit.text()
    # validate user input and store as 'SBI' if it is a 9-digit number
    if sbi.isdigit() and len(sbi) == 9:
        SBI = sbi
    else:
        # show error message if user input is not valid
        QMessageBox.warning(None, "Error", "Invalid input, please enter a 9-digit number.")

####################################################################################


# assuming 'SBI' is saved from earlier
url = "https://environment.data.gov.uk/arcgis/rest/services/RPA/LandParcels/MapServer/0/query?where=SBI=" + SBI + "&outFields=*&outSR=27700&f=geojson"
print(url)

# symbolise imported layer with red outline

my_string = url

fn = my_string
layer = iface.addVectorLayer(fn, '', 'ogr')
layer.setName("SBI=" + SBI + ' (parcels)')
symbol = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'border_width_map_unit_scale': '3x:0,0,0,0,0,0', 'color': '0,0,0,0', 'joinstyle': 'bevel', 'offset': '0,0', 'offset_map_unit_scale': '3x:0,0,0,0,0,0', 'offset_unit': 'MM', 'outline_color': 'red', 'outline_style': 'solid', 'outline_width': '0.3', 'outline_width_unit': 'MM', 'style': 'solid'})
layer.renderer().setSymbol(symbol)
layer.triggerRepaint()

#####################################################################################

# clear the SBI from recall

SBI = None

# zoom to newly created layer

# assume 'layer' is the newly created layer
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

# zoom to the extent of the layer
canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())

# refresh the canvas
canvas.refresh()

######################################################################################
```

Comment: If you are creating a script for the processing toolbox, you don't need an `InputDialog`, you can just set your script to have an input text parameter for the 9 digit SBI and the processing toolbox will set it up for you. Just like when you launch an existing tool, there are parameters of different types that you need to input values into.  Something like ["Writing new Processing algorithms as Python scripts | The @alg decorator"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#the-alg-decorator).